# NOT IN operator issue Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Here is my query:

```
Select a.* from Table1 a, Table2 b
Where 
a.tid=b.tid and 
b.createddate=(Select max(createddate) from Table2) and
a.tid not in (Select distinct tid from Table3);
```

The problem is I know this should return some valid output but it does not. The issue us with the last line in the **a.tid not in (Select distinct tid from Table3);** if I replace Select distinct tid from Table3 with hard coded values like ('T001','T002','T003','T004') then it works fine and returns data.

Whats wrong? Am I missing something? Please help.

Comment: :manually run the query `Select distinct tid from Table3` ,if this query returns any record as null ,then not in will not return any result

Comment: Also, remove the distinct, it is not helping performance.

Comment: Gaurav that query returns data. RedFilter- Thanks I have removed the distinct.

Comment: @Ram:Can you re-write the NOT IN query as `NOT IN (Select tid from Table3 where tid is not null)` , if tid is not primary key just to confirm

Comment: an oldie but goodie: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:442029737684

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select a.* from Table1 a, Table2 b
Where 
a.tid=b.tid and 
b.createddate=(Select max(createddate) from Table2) and
a.tid not in (Select tid from Table3 where tid is not null);
```

As all the people in the comments mentioned, if there is at least one row with a null value for tid in table3 you will get no rows returned.  This is because to Oracle null is like saying "I don't know what this value is".  Oracle can't say with certainty that the value you are searching for is definitely not in your sub-select because it doesn't know what this "not-known" value actually is.  Also, the documentation says it works that way: 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions013.htm

Another option would be to write the query as:

```
Select a.* from Table1 a, Table2 b
Where 
a.tid=b.tid and 
b.createddate=(Select max(createddate) from Table2) and
not exists (Select null from Table3 t3 where t3.tid = a.tid);
```

The handling of nulls is one of the major differences between not exists and not in.

Comment: :I am assuming the same thing and asked him to do the same in comments to confirm ,but as he said tid returns data :(

Comment: Craig,Gaurav yes that was it. Once I added tid is not null in the subquery it worked. Craig a special thanks for explaining it.

Comment: @GauravSoni - The issue is all about a subtlety in how NOT IN works.  If there are ANY rows in Table3 that have a null tid, his original query would ALWAYS return no rows, regardless of what the other data was.

Comment: @Craig:The same thing i am trying to find out with Ram ,otherwise your explaination tells everything :) +1

Answer (score 0):

Your query, slightly rewritten:

```
Select a.*
from Table1 a join
     Table2 b 
     on a.tid=b.tid 
where b.createddate=(Select max(createddate) from Table2) and
      a.tid not in (Select distinct tid from Table3)
```

What this tells me is that the tid with the maximum create date from Table2 is in Table3.

To test this, get the maximum create date from table2.  Then get all records in table1  that correspond to this max.  You will find that these are also in table3.

If I had to speculate, you might want the max create date per table in Table2, rather than the overall max.

By the way, in Oracle (and most other databases) the distinct in the last subquery is redundant.  The database should be smart enough to remove duplicates in this case.

Comment: Gordon no the tid with the maximum create date from Table2 is not in Table3. That's whats puzzling.